# Switching body parts/clothing efficiently?

Tags: drivers, asset-browser

From what I can tell, the only really viable way that I know of for switching body parts is putting drivers on an armature to toggle different limb types based on the driver. While this is fine, it's often quite tedious. (It also leaves a lot of extra stuff lying around in the outliner - even when sorted into collections, but that's a minor complaint.)

I was wondering, what other ways could this be done? The asset browser seems capable of storing characters and poses, but what about switchable limbs? Specifically, limb variants. I.e. one guy may have two regular legs, and another guy may have a peg leg.

Being able to click on the person (or armature, whatever is required) and swapping a limb mesh from the asset browser would be amazing, but I'm not surprised if this isn't possible. So, what other ways have people accomplished this with ease? Perhaps any addons?

Of note, I'm searching for a way to set them differently on multiple copies/instances so they can all have different appearances.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it comes down to how you want to use your assets.
You can think of it as either wanting variable assets or building assets by manually picking a few various parts.

If you want to make assets from a limited amount of various parts, and want to hand-pick them manually, and never change them again, then you don't need such a system. You could just have a bunch of well-- organized parts in an asset browser and import what you need only. If you have some variants you frequently use together, maybe make assets out of them too.

If you need to generate a high volume of variants procedurally, or be able to make changes through time in animation, or having a one click solution for premade variants for many artists to use, then often it's better to have a unique asset that can isolate variants either with a simple GUI or procedurally, possibly animate visibility. That's where making drivers in rigs is one efficient way to go.

It is good to know that, although drivers are one way to create interactions between different properties, it isn't the only one. For example, some rigs make use of some python scripts to toggle collections. The advantage being that it virtually unloads any content from the collection, which is more memory efficient.

Comment: It's really annoying that you can't turn off collections via drivers. But alas.... That's why I use view layers, but they're annoying because you can't sort them. But at least you can animate when a view layer is active via NLA.

Comment: And yeah, the thing with this is, there's going to be reusing assets for different characters so I'll have to make rig drivers for sure. I was just hoping there might've been a different way other than that since it can be a little frustrating working with the syntax. I've seen people suggesting geometry nodes but that's just overkill.